# How to follow logs while avoiding line wrapping w/ horizontal scroll enabled?

Tags: terminal, text-formatting, tail

In the terminal, if I don't want to have logs of a program wrap, I can pipe those to `less -S`.

However, horizontal scroll with keyboard doesn't work unless I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and after that, I don't know how to re-enter the follow mode.

Questions:

1. Am I only able to scroll horizontally after I detach from follow mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?
2. Is there any way to re-enter follow mode after that?

If not, is there any more convenient way that allows me to follow the scroll of a log file while 1. not wrapping and 2. not cutting (allows horizontal scroll when needed)?

Answer (score 0):

`man less` :

```
       F      Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file  is
              reached.   Normally  this  command would be used when already at
              the end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a  file
              which  is  growing  while  it is being viewed.  (The behavior is
              similar to the "tail -f" command.)  To  stop  waiting  for  more
              data,  enter the interrupt character (usually ^C).  On some sys‐
              tems you can also use ^X.
```

Comment: yes my issue is after ^C, the only thing I can do is `q` which quits, I can't re-enter follow mode. If you are suggesting to press 'F' that doesn't work either. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Go to the end of file and then hit `F`.